# Join other tables from comma separated value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Although many questions on the same topic I haven't been able to find the right solution.
I'm using a piece of software that aggregates IDs to another table as a comma separated value instead of a junction table.

The software exposes three views `Department`, `Team` and `Task`.

For `Department`

```
| ID     |  NAME |
|--------|-------|
|  12345 |    IT |
|  25695 |    HR |
|  89685 |   PAY |
|  47896 |   OPS |
```

`Team`

```
| ID     |  NAME |    DEPARTMENT |
|--------|-------|---------------|
|  34252 | TEAM1 |         12345 |
|  54234 | TEAM2 |         12345 |
|  52385 | TEAM1 |          NULL |
|  91231 | TEAM1 |         89685 |
```

`Task`

```
| ID     |  NAME |             Team |
|--------|-------|------------------|
|      1 |    Ta |34252,54234,52385 |
|      2 |    Tb |      52385,91231 |
|      3 |    Tc |             NULL |
|      4 |    Td |            34252 |
```

I try to achieve the following structure:

```
| DepID  |   Dep | TeamID |   Team | TaskID |  Task |
|--------|-------|--------|--------|--------|-------|
```

With a row for every Task, potentially, appearing more than once, if assigned to multiple Teams, and not at all if assigned to no Team or if Team not assigned to a Department yet. Again I only have these three views. What would be the most efficient way to create said structure? I'm on SQLServer 2017.

I've tried starting from the Task table `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT` and then `RIGHT JOIN` to Teams as well as Starting from Department `LEFT JOIN` Teams.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Posting the query that you tried will increase the chances of getting an answer to this question by 10x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2016+. Something like this:

> ---
>
> ```
> SELECT d.ID AS DepID
>   , d.NAME AS Dep
>   , t.ID AS TeamID
>   , t.NAME AS Team
>   , tsk.TaskID
>   , tsk.Task
> FROM
> (  
>   SELECT tsk.ID AS TaskID
>     , tsk.Name AS Task
>     , ss.[value] AS TeamID
>   FROM Task tsk
>   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tsk.Team, ',') ss
> ) tsk
> LEFT JOIN Team t ON t.ID = tsk.TeamID
> LEFT JOIN Department d ON d.ID = t.DEPARTMENT
> ```
>
> | DepID | Dep | TeamID | Team | TaskID | Task |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12345 | IT | 34252 | TEAM1 | 1 | Ta |
> | 12345 | IT | 54234 | TEAM2 | 1 | Ta |
> | *null* | *null* | 52385 | TEAM1 | 1 | Ta |
> | *null* | *null* | 52385 | TEAM1 | 2 | Tb |
> | 89685 | PAY | 91231 | TEAM1 | 2 | Tb |
> | 12345 | IT | 34252 | TEAM1 | 4 | Td |
>
> ---
>
> [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BH0iNvzf)